# how to get category list according to store_id in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I am trying to get a list of category according to store_id , but all my tries have failed

ive tried

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId(21)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

but it gives me all the categories from all the stores, i have tried

```
->addFieldToFilter('store_id', '21')
```

and
    ->addStoreFilter(21)

but with no luck , any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanking you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Categories in magento doesn't have to Store relations ( because its used by stores ( store can point to subcategory as its root category for instance ) etc.. ) So any category you create it will be visible in all stores.

But is has attribute is_active ( which is store view scope ).

So to get the categories in specific store ( you need to make sure its not active in other stores )

and Filter with the attribute

```
->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

This works in 1.9

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$storeId = 21;
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$storeId=21;
->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$storeId)
```